# Flask Restless with custom query

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

Can someone provide a working example as described [in the docs here](https://flask-restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customizing.html#custom-queries);

```
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    @classmethod
    def query(cls):
        return get_query_for_current_user(cls)
```

What should be returned by `'get_query_for_current_user()'`?

Answer (score 1):

You should return the query itself..

```py
original_query = db.session.query(cls)
```

This will return the original query. After that you can basically add any filters to it and return the modified query.

For example.

```
if user.is_auth:
    condition = (cls.id == 1)
else:
    condition = (cls.id == 2)
return original_query.filter(condition)
```